# Reading .dat file as string in c#

Tags: c#, .net, io, binary, filereader

I have a .dat file which contains some values .Now when i am trying to read these values i am getting some unreadable values like `��#����+e��I��`.I am using following code to read the file ..

```
System.IO.StreamReader oRead = null;
string[] FirstLine = new string[500];
int lineNo = 0;
oRead = System.IO.File.OpenText(@"F:\\Bills\\TAXAZGSC.DAT");
lineNo = 0;
while (!oRead.EndOfStream)
{
  FirstLine[lineNo] = oRead.ReadLine();
  lineNo += 1;
}
for (int i = 0; i <= (lineNo - 1); i++)
{
  Console.WriteLine(FirstLine[i].ToString());

}
```

Please help me to correct it.Thanks..

Comment: It sounds like if they are `.DAT` files, then they are either: **NOT** properly encoded strings, or they are raw binary data, which is more likely.

Comment: Tell us more about the `.dat` file. Did you create it? If so, how? If not how do you know how to read the data?

Comment: @EBrown The file is in `binary` format.Am sorry i got this file from a hardware machine.As of now i am changing the format of `.DAT` file to `.zip` and after unzipping the file i am able to read the file as text.This i am doing manually.I want to do these programatically using c#.How to do it ?

Comment: Mandatory reading: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404280%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @EBrown Okay.I am using `.net 4.0` .I saw the link that you shared to me before but my .net version is not matching.For the same sake i changed tried to convert the to zip by following code line `File.Move(@"F:\\Bills\\TAXAZGSC.DAT", Path.ChangeExtension(@"F:\\Bills\\TAXAZGSC.DAT", ".zip"));` .Zip is happening fine but i am not able to extract it.I am getting file not of Zip type error..

Comment: Where it says **.NET Framework #.#** select **Other Versions** -> *.NET Framework 4.0*. I also recommend you investigate the file itself to determine that it truly is a **.ZIP** file.

Comment: @jurgemaister I did not created the .DAT file .As of now i am changing the format of .DAT file to .zip and after unzipping the file i am able to read the file as text.This i am doing manually.Please tell me how to do it programatically

Comment: @RamPandey That changes everything. You have a `.zip` file named `.dat` delete this question, try again, and if you fail, post a new one.

Comment: @EBrown Where it says .NET Framework #.# select Other Versions -> .NET Framework 4.0.Please elaborate this .I am very sorry i am newbie for this .I shared my file at `http://www.filedropper.com/taxazgsc` Please check it ..Thanks

Comment: @EBrown Please help me.I need your assistance

Comment: @RamPandey Go to the URL I sent you before (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404280%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and follow the *first* example. Skip the `ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory` portion and simply do the `ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory`.

Comment: @EBrown I am sorry to tell that i am using VS2010 and so i can not use this code .How to go in this case?

Answer (score 0):

"DAT" is usually used as generic extension for binary data in custom binary formats (other similar extensions are "BIN" and "RAW"). It is not possible to view such binary data as string directly as data usually contains raw binary representation of different types like numbers, collections and sometimes string.

What you can do:

- find reader/parser for particular binary format. Some already exist in .Net framework (like ZIP archives or .Net serialized data), some have existing libraries.
- find specification and read file yourself, possibly using `BinaryReader` class
- find converter to more readable/text format
- scan for sequences that look like strings and display just those (i.e. if you just care to show resource strings from DLL file)
- show file as string with sequence of HEX values